# Div not recognizing hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have set up a hover effect to show an icon overlay and filter over the instagram feed on a website I am working on. When I go on inspect and set the element state to hover it works perfectly. However when actually using the website and hovering over the images she hover effect does not appear.

Why is the hover state not being recognized?

```css
#insta-feed>a>img,
.ig__overlay--container {
  width: 25vw !important;
  height: 25vw !important;
}

.ig__overlay--container {
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 300;
}

.overlay__container {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 300;
}

#insta-feed>.overlay__container>div.ig__overlay--container:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-image: url({{ 'icon-socialig-menu.svg' | asset_url }} );
}
```

```html
<div class="social__container">
  <div id="insta-feed" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="flex flex-row overlay__container">
      <div class="ig__overlay--container">
      </div>
      <div class="ig__overlay--container">
      </div>
      <div class="ig__overlay--container">
      </div>
      <div class="ig__overlay--container">
      </div>
    </div
</div>
```

Comment: The images aren't inside the divs referred to by the hover selector in your CSS. So hovering over the images won't trigger any hover CSS on the divs.

Comment: @Adrian even if I move the overlay__container div outside the social container and adjust the hover style I still am not seeing the hover effect.

Comment: If you want hovering over the images to do something to the divs, the images need to be inside the divs. The divs can stay where they are.

Comment: @Adrian I know, my point is that there is something blocking the hover over the divs. Even if I mode them elsewhere on the page they are not showing the hover effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong here, but I think that because `pointer-events` is set to automatically inherent, the child `div.ig__overlay` is getting the property `pointer-events: none` from it's parent element. That would also explain why you can set the state manually, even though it can't receive mouse events normally.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events?v=example

"The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases."

Comment: Interesting, I will have to find another way now to allow for the links behind the hover div to be clickable through the div covering them. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really follow your code well, is there something stopping you from putting all of your content into that div where you apply the filter? If not, you can use an event listener on either the entire element to make it work like a link, or just img if you don't want the padding to be clickable.

Comment: The image links are being generated from an app that loads the most recent 4 instagram pictures. As such I can't adjust the link code very much and thought the best solution would be to create new divs which would have the desired hover effect and place them on top of the image links.

Comment: If you can't easily adjust the code so that the app feeds into your divs, then perhaps use jQuery's .wrap() function? You have a JQuery tag so I'm assuming that's available to you. .wrap() will let you create html structures around existing elements with javascript, like in the code below.

`$("#insta-feed a").wrap( "<div class='ig__overlay--container'></div>" );`

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/